# Why doesn't twitter.com load on my home network?

Tags: networking, internet-connection, wget, twitter, time-capsule

I'm trying to figure out why my twitter clients stopped working. I am unable to load twitter via twitter clients or http://twitter.com/ on all machines connected to my home network. The connection times out before any data is returned.

So far I know:

1. I can `ping twitter.com` and I get decent response times and 0% packet loss.
2. I can't `wget twitter.com`. Whenever it tries to connect to port 80, the process hangs and throws timeout errors.
3. I can connect to twitter using twitter clients and the mobile web over cellular data.

I don't know how to continue troubleshooting this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

#### Edit:

Traceroute, as requested:

```
 1  wireless_broadband_router (192.168.1.1)  4.325 ms  0.888 ms  0.807 ms
 2  74.103.153.1 (74.103.153.1)  10.804 ms  14.438 ms  9.962 ms
 3  g0-9-4-5.phlapa-lcr-22.verizon-gni.net (130.81.109.26)  17.474 ms  25.869 ms  15.271 ms
 4  * ae10-0.phil-bb-rtr2.verizon-gni.net (130.81.163.140)  16.302 ms
    130.81.199.20 (130.81.199.20)  16.834 ms
 5  0.xe-4-0-0.xl4.iad8.alter.net (152.63.40.234)  14.788 ms
    0.xe-4-1-3.xl4.iad8.alter.net (152.63.5.141)  16.784 ms  19.709 ms
 6  tengige0-7-0-0.gw1.iad8.alter.net (152.63.36.49)  23.402 ms
    tengige0-5-2-0.gw1.iad8.alter.net (152.63.39.2)  21.330 ms
    tengige0-7-2-0.gw1.iad8.alter.net (152.63.35.153)  22.339 ms
 7  teliasonera-gw.customer.alter.net (152.179.50.234)  19.526 ms  16.635 ms  18.234 ms
 8  ash-b1-link.telia.net (213.155.137.228)  20.796 ms
    ash-b1-link.telia.net (213.155.130.90)  41.461 ms
    ash-b1-link.se.telia.net (80.91.245.222)  96.737 ms
 9  twitter-ic-302255-ash-b2.c.telia.net (62.115.33.198)  17.702 ms
    twitter-ic-302253-ash-b2.c.telia.net (62.115.33.194)  23.156 ms  20.432 ms
10  ae50.atl1-er2.twttr.com (199.16.159.71)  71.761 ms  34.234 ms  39.782 ms
11  199.16.156.6 (199.16.156.6)  39.021 ms  38.392 ms  37.139 ms
```

#### Edit 2:

Twitter fails on 3 different MacBook Pros and two different iPhones, but loads successfully when the iPhones are switched to cellular data. The affected clients are Tweetbot 3 for iPhone, Twitter for iPhone, Tweetbot for Mac and twitter.com.

My home network setup is an Apple Time Machine connected to a Verizon Fios Actiontec router. The Time Machine acts as the wireless access point, and wireless is disabled on the Actiontec.

Connecting directly to the Actiontec directly via ethernet allows Twitter to load.

Comment: From here, HTTP requests are forwarded to HTTPS and thus port 443. What happens when you try https ?

Comment: HTTPS also fails. I also cleared out my browser cache in case there happened to be a 301 redirect that was cached, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Does this happen with both wired and wireless? Have you checked router settings or tried to reset the router? Call your ISP?

Comment: can you do a traceroute from your computer to https://twitter.com?

Comment: @CharlieRB I restarted the router and looked at its settings. Most of this networking stuff is hieroglyphics to me, but I didn't see anything that looked wrong. I didn't want to play too much with the router settings because I have a home server and port forwarding set up. This issue just started popping up last night, and I haven't touched those settings for months.

Comment: @sgtbeano added to the question

Comment: This happens on all devices ( Android, Windows, iOS )? Have you tried to reset the configuration of your router? Please provide configuration information about the home network in question.  You can forward the ports in a matter of minutes, if you are really worried, just backup the settings before the reset

Comment: Have you added a firewall of any kind?  As this started last night, have you changed anything at all on your network, added any new devices, done something new with your home server?

Comment: I support @Ramhound, please test on another device, so we're sure this is a network problem and not a software issue (Which can reside on a firewall like Windows')

Comment: @Ramhound I added some new info to the question. Looks like a possible issue with the Time Machine.

Comment: If this just started happening last night, and you have not changed any settings, I would suggest contacting your ISP.

Comment: @sgtbeano I already thought about the firewall, and I lowered the built in settings on my Actiontec router to minimum (allow all). Doesn't change anything.

Comment: @sgtbeano No I don't have any AppleCare or support on it - it's going on 2 years old now anyway.

Comment: Which generation Time Capsule do you have? (from this page -> http://support.apple.com/manuals/%23airport)

Comment: @CharlieRB well, seeing that I *can* connect via a wired connection, I doubt it is an ISP problem.

Comment: @sgtbeano 4th gen, 2TB

Comment: It sounds like something is wrong with your Time Capsule, I've checked the (very thin) docs on it and I think you might need to do a reset of the settings (you can use this guide to setup your port forwards again ->http://must-know-mac.blogspot.co.uk/2008/07/how-to-port-forward-time-capsule.html)

Comment: @sgtbeano possibly... The Time Capsule is just setup as a wifi bridge, so the port forwarding is done in the Actiontec. I've looked over the settings and it looks like there is a firmware update available. Maybe I'll upgrade it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the update about the wired connection working. There is certainly some dynamic question and comment activity!

Comment: Can  you remove the Time Capsule and try using just the Actiontec wireless?  Does it work then?

Comment: Setup the Actiontec to use an alternative DNS solution ( OpenDNS, Google DNS, ect ).

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think this is a DNS issue - I consulted with others running FiOS in my area, and twitter works for them.

Comment: @heavyd I switched to just Actiontec wireless and it works now.

Comment: Is using the Actiontec an ok long-term solution, or are you wanting to get this working with the Time Capsule?

Comment: @heavyd it's an *ok* solution, but not a desirable solution. I switched over to the Actiontec to maintain connectivity while I ran a firmware update on the Time Capsule (investigating the settings made me realize that it was out of date). After the update, everything is working normally.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded the Time Capsule firmware from v7.6 to v7.6.4 and it corrected the issue.